# all pair sums between 1 and n without repeating easy

Tags: algorithm, sum

I have this way to do task:

```
for(int i =1;i<=n;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if(i+j==k//it is my variable which i know){
            out.print(i+" "+j);
    }
 }
```

But it prints numbers twice. I want to print once. Can you show fastest way (i.e. not simplest but in terms of operations) to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know k and know the range of i, then just solve the equation:

j = k-i

j_min = max(1, k-i_max) = max(1, k-n)

j_max = min(n, k-i_min) = min(n, k-1)

So one single for-loop from j_min to j_max and then print (k-j,j).